# How to Monitor the Health Level and Functionalities of Relays Connected to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I am building an application to control more than 20 raspberry pis where each of which controls 32 relays connected to electrical locks. having a big system like this would require self-diagnoses mechanisim to know when and where the problem in the system exists e.g. relay, lock, raspberry, etc.

Is there a mechanism to build such a system to diagnose the raspberry pi's connected components every now and then or especially on boot-up to check all relays' and locks' health and functionality e.g. if a lock is released successfully or not?

Comment: Ah let me see.  Your question is a bit too board.  Let us eat the big elephant bite by bite, say, in 3 bites: (1) How to monitor one of the 20 Rpi's is alive and well? (2) How to monitor one of the 32 relays of any Rpi is alive and well? (3) Now all together, how to monitor each of the 32 relays of each of the 20 Rpis are alive and well?  If you agree we can structure the big question into these 3 smaller questions, and if yes, which question you would like to start first, then we can start.  Counter suggestions welcome! :)

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01. Yes, but for 1st question, I already have a system in place where each RPi sends a signal (pulse) to the system to inform that it is alive. you can say we still have questions 2 and 3 for relays and the electrical locks. thanks :)

Comment: Good.  Now perhaps you can give me the links to the relay module and solenoid door lock you would like to monitor.  It is OK if you don't have the links in hand.  I can use pseudo standard models, say 5V relay and 12V door lock.  But it would make the design easier if you can let us know if the relay module is 16 channel, using GPIO, UART, Ethernet/Wifi control etc.

Comment: Or if you don't have any door lock in mind, you can look at the following catalog and let me know which ones you like to use: AliExpress Door Lock Catalog
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-solenoid-lock.html

Comment: thanks @tlfong01 Yes, it's 16 channel 5v relays. I am going to use two decoders (MCP23017 I2C) to control 32 relays using 16 channel relay board. the electrical lock is 12v

Comment: I have already purchased an electricl lock (https://shopee.com.my/product/140618845/2803559381)

Comment: Good, so your solenoid door lock is a mini 12V one.  Now let me show you a typical relay driving solenoid lock schematic.  The relay is just a typical one.  You can use any one similar.  But if you have already bought one, you might also like to give me the link. https://imgur.com/gallery/UbIVZdb

Comment: And it is a bit difficult to check if the bolt of the lock is moving to the correct position, locking or unlocking the door.  A much easier way is to check if the relay is switching on or off the 12V power.  So in my schematic, the NO terminal getting on/off 12V power is connected to the solenoid lock.  You can add an extra wire at the same terminal and connect it back to Rpi.  In other words, Rpi is just checking if 12V for solenoid door is on or off, NOT checking if the lock bolt is moving to the correct lock/unlock position.

Comment: If you insist to check if the bolt is in the correct position, you need to let the bolt pull or push a micro switch, say, and connect the micro switch to a 3V3 source, and feed this switch status signal back to Rpi.

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01. but I am looking to a way without doing any circut design. I was thinking if there is a way to do the checking using raspberry. What in my mind at the moment is to have extra wires from relay output and lock ground connected back to raspberry gpio as input just to sense if there is a current coming back when the relay is closed and lock is in operation. I have not worked much on eleronics since graduation as my focus currently on software but this is what in my mind at the moment

Comment: Ah, using 2 mcp23017 GPIO extender (we don't usually call it a "decoder") to control two 16 channel 5V relays is neat. By the way, there are now too many comments in this little space and some comments got squeezed out.  So I would suggest to move to chat, where all comments are sequentially sorted, and you can select which comment to reply.  See you in chat room later.  Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100302/discussion-between-abdulkarim-kanaan-and-tlfong01).

Answer (score 0):

You can not check the health of a relay module. But you can check if one is on or off. Try to read the pinouts and set the code and add them with your boot configs.